# Numeric(x,x) to Decimal(x,x) Sql Server weirdness

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-profiler

I have a really weird problem. I have a stored proc which has the following params:

```
@Id int OUTPUT,
@DataSourceId int, 
@OwnerId int, 
@Size numeric(16,6),
@SizeUnitId int,
@LayCanFrom datetime, 
@LayCanTo datetime, 
@DischargeDate datetime, 
@IMO int,
@ProductIds inttable readonly,
@LoadPortIds inttable readonly, 
@DischargePortIds inttable readonly, 
@LoadCountryIds inttable readonly, 
@DischargeCountryIds inttable readonly,
@LoadZoneIds inttable readonly, 
@DischargeZoneIds inttable readonly, 
@FreightRate numeric(16,6), 
@FreightRateUnitId int, 
@StateId int, 
@OriginalMessage varchar(max),
@Comments varchar(max) = null
```

The particular param of interest here is @Size numeric(16,6). 
On C# side, when I am calling the stored proc, I am declaring the param as:

```
var paramSize = command.Parameters.AddParameter("@Size", this.Size);
paramSize .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
paramSize .Size = 16;
paramSize .Precision = 6;
```

I am getting the connection string as:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
                (context.Connection as EntityConnection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            // Call function to execute the stored proc.
        }
```

Then I open the connection, and do the usual `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`
Now @Size is passed in as 75000.000000, which should be fine, as the field is numeric(16,6). In fact, I already have records in the same table, which have values like 75000.000000 in that Size column. However, when I call `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`, it comes back with

> Parameter value '75000.000000' is out of range.

So, instead of passing in the parameter, I decided to default @Size in the stored proc to 75000.000000. And guess what? It works! Another interesting thins is that I am trying to capture the SP execution using SQL Profiler, and no matter what I try, or which events I select for capture, I am unable to see the SP execution. Is this because I am fetching my connection string from EF storeconnection? Has anybody encountered something like this before? This is driving me a bit crazy! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set [`Scale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx) instead of [`Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size.aspx):

```
paramSize.Precision = 16;
paramSize.Scale = 6;
```

Also note, that `decimal` (or `numeric`) is defined [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

```
 decimal [ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]
```

The first number is a *precision*, and the second number is a *scale*.
So, `@Size numeric(16,6)` means "precision is 16, and scale is 6".

You're confusing this too.

Comment: Facepalm! I should read MSDN a bit better before I post question. I feel like an idiot! Thanks a lot!